# function nativeEvent(window, evenType, message) doesn't work in pyside2

Tags: python, events, pyside2

I've got a window frameLessWindowHint and I want to user can drag and move the window. I found file that work with function nativeEvent but in my script it doesn't work. I don't know where is my mistake.
Here is my function :

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtWebEngineWidgets
import socket

def init_gui(application, port=0, width=800, height=600, window_title="", icon="appicon.png", argv=None, borderless=False):
    
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    if port == 0:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind(('localhost', 0))
        port = sock.getsockname()[1]
        sock.close()

    # Application Level
    qtapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(argv)
    webapp = ApplicationThread(application, port)
    webapp.start()
    qtapp.aboutToQuit.connect(webapp.terminate)

    # Main Window Level
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    window.resize(width, height)
    window.setWindowTitle(window_title)
    window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(icon))
    if borderless :
        window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

    # WebView Level
    webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(window)
    window.setCentralWidget(webView)

    # WebPage Level
    page = WebPage('http://localhost:{}'.format(port))
    page.home()
    webView.setPage(page)
    window.show()


    def nativeEvent(window, eventType, message):
        msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG.from_address(message.__int__())
        if msg.message == win32con.WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
            info = ctypes.cast(msg.lParam, ctypes.POINTER(MINMAXINFO)).contents
            info.ptMaxSize.x = self._rect.width()
            info.ptMaxSize.y = self._rect.height()
            info.ptMaxPosition.x, info.ptMaxPosition.y = 0, 0
        if msg.message == win32con.WM_NCHITTEST:
            return True, win32con.HTCAPTION
    return qtapp.exec_()
```

Problem is function nativeEvent(window, evenType, message). It doesn't work and no error is catch.
Please help me, thanks you

I try to do_something when event drag is detected on my window web application.

Comment: It doesn't work because it's never called nor exposed in a way it could be used. That function should be overridden in a subclass, right now it's just useless.